# NextAuth getSession in NextJs Backend

Tags: session, next.js, backend, next-auth, next.js13

Hi I am trying to get session to check if there's a google authentication or no in the backend to give access to users only.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  // ...
}
```

I don't know if I am trying to do is right. Please tell me how if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `getServerSession` as NextAuth.js documentation says. It may drastically reduce response time when used over `getSession` method.

Check out the [Docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#unstable_getserversession).